# Event equivalent to load for top-level await

Tags: javascript, dom-events, top-level-await

Consider the following [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qutelotibe/edit?html,output) (content pasted below as well).

You can see that the `window` `load` event is fired before the `module` with a top-level `await` has finished. I've observed a similar thing when using the `load` event of a `script` tag.

Is there an equivalent event that would wait for a `module` with a top-level await to have completed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script id='async' type="module">
    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      document.body.innerHTML += 'async: Window load event fired</br>';
    });
    document.body.innerHTML += 'async: Starting module</br>';
    document.body.innerHTML += `async: Long op</br>`;
    const now = (new Date()).getTime();
    await sleep(1000);
    document.body.innerHTML += `async: Finished module ${(new Date()).getTime() - now}</br>`;
  </script>
  <script id='sync' type="module">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      document.body.innerHTML += 'sync: Window load event fired</br>';
    });
    document.body.innerHTML += 'sync: Starting module</br>';
    document.body.innerHTML += `sync: Long op</br>`;
    const now = (new Date()).getTime();
    const a = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
      a[i] = i^2;
    }
    document.body.innerHTML += `sync: Finished module ${(new Date()).getTime() - now}</br>`;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```